# Redirect with compact value in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6, http-redirect

Route :

```
Route::get('merchantTrans/{id}','MerchantController@merchant');
```

Merchant Controller :

```
public function merchant($id){
    $merchant = Merchant::whereId($id)->get();
    return redirect('Merchant view')->with(compact('merchant'));
}
```

View Route :

```
Route::view('Merchant view','merchant.listview')->name('Merchant view');
```

I cannot pass merchant compact value to view.

Produce error

#### Undefined variable: merchant

Any other best way?

Comment: If you're trying to redirect to a route, isn't it suppose to be redirect()->route('Merchant route')?

Comment: Ya i tried, Even compact value cannot be pass @OluwatobiSamuelOmisakin

Comment: you're passing `merchant` but using `merch`? indeed, that will result to undefined variable error.

Comment: Thats Spelling mistake @Wreigh

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this

```
return redirect()->route('Merchant view')->with( ['merchant' => $merchant] );
```

In blade file :

```
<?php $merchants = Session::get('merchant'); ?>
@foreach ($merchants as $merchant)
    //your code
@endforeach
```

Hope it helps you !

Comment: But how can i separate single value from this

Comment: using foreach loop

Comment: Dono How to write Session:get in foreach loop

Comment: This pass value to session not directly to blade context

Comment: it solves the error, if you want to use in blade template use curly brackets like {{ $merchant }} inside for each loop. Thanks, you solved my error.

Answer (score 1):

The `Route::view` is made for the static views with static parameters passed like :

```
Route::view('Merchant view','merchant.listview', ['param1' => 'value1']);
```

Since you want to pass dynamic parameters then it will be better to use the regular route passing by the related controller `action` and retrieving the desired data.

Anyway you could use `Redirect::route()` like :

```
return Redirect::route('Merchant view',['merchant' => base64_encode($merchant)]);
```

And get the passed variable in the blade side as a HTTP parameter using :

```
{{ base64_decode(Request::get('merchant')) }}
```

Comment: I've tried this locally and work just fine, what the problem ?

Comment: {{ Request::get('merchant') }}          shows nothing

Comment: Update your question with the current content after your update

Comment: But first replace `Merchant::whereId($id)->get();` by `Merchant::find($id);` adn make sure `dd($merchant)` return the right value

Comment: But how can i separate single value from this

Comment: Which value you want to get ?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass value from controller  to view by using compact
the Exact syntax should be like this

```
$user_detail=array('field1'=>1,'field2'=>2);
return view('dashboard',compact('user_detail'));
```

The variable name(user_detail) should be same as the name in compact. Right syntax for laravel 5.4 and heigher versions.

Answer (score -1):

Hello you can use the following way to get compact data.

```
return view('admin/users/userdetails', compact('transaction', 'title'));
```

OR

```
return redirect('/userdetails', compact('transaction', 'title'));
```

i have use the following syntax in my project to compact data while redirect to other page.

thank you.

Comment: @SamuelHenry you pass this in your controller file from where you want to complete process and redirect to URL and then after it's not working then okay i will send you another example if i have any. sorry for this inconvenience.