# how to pass button from controller to view with url?

Tags: html, laravel, button, model-view-controller, controller

i am trying to pass button from controller to view here i tried this code

```
    function sendbutton (){

      $order = 1;
      return   '<a href="{{ url("user/order/geOrder/") . $order) }}" class="btn btn-primary" style="color:white">Edit Order</a>'
    }
```

it render successfully but problem is that my axpecting url should be "https://example.org/user/order/geOrder/1"

but i am getting url https://example.org/user/order/create/Order/by/%7B%7B%20url(

which is wrong
we can also use

```
route('edit.order' , $order)
```

i dont know the method any help?

Comment: It would be better to return the actions using compact values. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52218545/redirect-with-compact-value-in-laravel/52219170

Comment: my scenerio is different i am already compacting but i have complex ajex call thats why i need to render return button

Comment: this {{ }} not working in laravel controller. it's only working inside blade view file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have some typo when calling the url you have an extra `)` after `$order`.
Second, when passing a string from controller to view there is no need to use `{{}}` to render variables, you must process it as a string and then pass it to view.
I think your function should be like this:

```
function sendbutton (){
    $order = 1;
    $url = url("user/order/geOrder") . '/' . $order;
    return  '<a href="'. $url .'" class="btn btn-primary" style="color:white">Edit Order</a>';
}
```